# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'libs.strings'

Tags: python, django

This is the error I am facing right, I google it a lot but solutions did not work, I am using python 3.7 in my django application.

Code:

```
from libs.strings import *
```

Error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'libs.strings'

Answer (score 0):

As I have checked the **libs** module from [pypi](https://pypi.org/project/libs/). The libs module doesn't seem to have strings. So doing `pip install libs` wont solve your problem.

Maybe **libs** could be a directory in your project you are trying to access. If so, then:

1. Check Proper path for libs folder.
2. In order to define libs as  a single package, add empty `__init__.py` file in each folder; so the whole directory system act as a python module.